# node.js mongoError not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm studying Node.js and i can'y find any solution.. my consol send me many messages an one is more particulary strange : GET/signup - - ms - -
has someone any idea about that ?
Thanks in advance !

```js
///////////////////////inclusion des librairies
 // 3 librairies pour gérer les messages flash
 var session = require('express-session');
 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 var flash = require('express-flash');
 //passerelle pour se connecter à node(node->bdd)
 var passport =require('passport');
 // stockage des sessions(id) et cookies côté serveur uniquement
 var mongoStore =require('connect-mongo')(session); // le session de express-session

//inclure al librairie  express
 var express = require('express');
// Inclusion de la librairie morgan (faire le lien avec la base de données)
var morgan = require('morgan');

// Inclusion de mongoose
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 //Inclusion moteur templates ejs
 var ejs = require('ejs');
  var engine =require('ejs-mate');
  // Inclusion de body parser pour les données des formulaires
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');



  /////////////////////fin des librairies ///////////////

// stocker l'objet express dans une variable plus courte
 
 var app = express();



//inclure le fichier secret.js
var secret = require('./config/secret');
 ////////////connexion à la bd avec mongoose///
 
 mongoose.connect(secret.database, // voir pour création de db en ligne !!
  {useNewUrlParser:true},
  function(err){
   if(err){console.log(err)
   }else{
    console.log('connexion OK');
   }
  });


/////////////////// gestion des Passerelles (middleware)/////////////////////////
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // pour le style
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.engine('ejs',engine);
app.set('view engine','ejs');
// les deux lignes ci-dessous pour récupérer les données des formulaires
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
// affichage messages flash et gestion des cookies
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
 resave :true,
 saveUninitialized:true,
 secret :secret.secretKey,
 store : new mongoStore({
  url:secret.database,
  autoReconnect:true })
}));

app.use(flash());

//authentification
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


////////////////définition du chemin des pages principales////////////////////////

var mainRoutes =require('./routes/main');
app.use(mainRoutes);

var userRoutes =require('./routes/user');
app.use(userRoutes);



//app.post()

//app.put()

//app.delete()
```

AND THE CONSOLE SAYS :

> Le serveur est lancé sur le port3000 (node:7828) DeprecationWarning:
>   collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
>   connexion OK (node:7828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError:
>   not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: "system.indexes",
>   documents: [[{ns admin.sessions} {key [{expires 1}]} {name expires_1}
>   {expireAfterSeconds 0} {unique false}]], ordered: true }
>       at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\NODE\ECommerce\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
>       at C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\NODE\ECommerce\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:497:72
>       at authenticateStragglers (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\NODE\ECommerce\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:443:16)
>       at Connection.messageHandler (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\NODE\ECommerce\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:477:5)
>       at TLSSocket. (C:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\NODE\ECommerce\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:333:22)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
>       at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
>       at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17) (node:7828)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:7828) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. GET /login - - ms - - GET
>   /login - - ms - - GET /login - - ms - - GET /signup - - ms - -

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The npm module `connect-mongo` can't handle `mongodb+srv://` connection strings. You'll have to use the older connection string types that start with `mongodb://`.

If you are using MongoDB Atlas I recommend to go to **connect** on the cluster view, then **connect your application** and then select Node.js **version 2.2.12, not 3.0**.

You probably also have to change the `/test` or `/admin` in your connection string to `/TheNameOfYourDatabase` with your database name there. (See [radihuq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58228641/5816268) below)

Comment: Tanks a lot ConstJS ! I didn't see your asweer before now. everything is working well !! Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it worked! @cessother Could you please mark it as answered? :)

Comment: I will do it with pleasure, but I have one  more question : How do I do to mark it as answered  ? :)

Comment: Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. This marks it as answered :)

Comment: been trying to solve this forever, this finally worked. thank you.  To help others-- this also surfaces as: MongoError: Cannot do raw queries on admin in atlas

Comment: It worked for me by just switching to version 2.2.12

Answer (score 5):

@ConstJS answer worked for me. Expanding on it a little bit -

If you're using Postman and your error looks like this:

> "errmsg": "not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: [..] }, $db: \"admin\" }"

Note this specific part:

> $db: \"admin\"

You'll want to change that to your DB name so go to your URI and find

```
mongodb.net:27017/admin
```

and change admin to your database name

Comment: This should be also an accepted answer. Thanks @Taslim

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer and added a reference to your answer in my answer above :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to access MongoDB's admin database and insert something which is not allowed. I am assuming you are using a connection string like:

```
mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017/admin
```

Make sure you update the `/admin` piece to the database you want to connect to.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your answer. I use this kind of connexion for mongodb Atlas : mongodb+srv://root:<password>@cluster0-zfgku.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true.  I can add user, but no session id, that's strange. Maybe there is a problem withe the library "connect-mongo" ?

Comment: If you can access the DB to save a user, then the connection is okay. I think your issue is related to not passing the Mongoose connection to the session. I think you may want to look into reusing your connection. Look at the section "Re-use a Mongoose connection" here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

Answer (score 0):

This error is specific to the fact that you are passing a url `mongo-connect` doesn't know how to handle. Instead of the URL, you can pass the `mongoose.Connection` object and use the `mongooseConnection` property in the `MongoStore` options object.

```
new mongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  autoReconnect: true 
})
```

In order for this to work, you'll need to establish a connection first and then pass the `mongoose.connection` object to your `mongoStore` class.

```
 mongoose.connect(secret.database, {useNewUrlParser:true}, function(err) {
    if(err) { 
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      app.use(session({
        resave :true,
        saveUninitialized:true,
        secret :secret.secretKey,
        store : new mongoStore({
          url:secret.database,
          autoReconnect:true })
      }));
      console.log('connexion OK');
    }
});
```

There are more elegant ways to handle it but that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this error is generic, I was getting this error as my connection string didn't have the name of database:

```
"mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@searchpractice0.rh7gx.mongodb.net/<NameOfDatabase>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```